# midi keyboard not working on all platforms

Tags: java, audio, midi

I made a [keyboard application](https://github.com/soundhaven/keyboard) a while ago that gets a midi soundbank as a resource from a jar, and uses it to get the instrument names contained in the soundbank.  This seems to work fine on machines using windows 7 with suns java 6 and in linux using suns java 6. However, this does not seem to work on machines using windows xp using the same version of java.  What seems to be happening is that the instrument array has not been loaded when the `getInstrumentName()` method is called.  The instrument array gets populated in the constructor of the `DefaultControl` class (second code sample).  Could someone please help me to understand why would this be the case, and why would it seem to be machine dependent?

I get the current instrument name like this:

```
data.setControls(new DefaultControls());
data.setKeyboard(new KeyboardPanel(data.getPressed()));
data.getKeyboard().setInstrumentName(data.getControls().getInstrumentName());
```

I get and load the soundbank like this:

```
this.synth=MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
synth.open();
synth.loadAllInstruments(
  MidiSystem.getSoundbank(
    getClass().getResourceAsStream("soundbank.gm")));

this.instrument=synth.getAvailableInstruments();
this.channels=synth.getChannels();
```

This is the method that is called to load the name is this:

```
public String getInstrumentName(){
    return instrument[selected_instrument].getName();
}
```

Comment: Any exceptions ? Possible JDK bug? http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4444193

Comment: Its an array index out of bounds exception that gets thrown.  Its odd because get name would only be called if no errors were thrown and the sound bank was loaded successfully.

Comment: This could be related to the bug that you referenced I will look into that.

Comment: I tested it with the soundbank outside of the jar on XP with JDK 1.6.0_24. I wonder what is different?

Answer (score 1):

MIDI sound banks, in Java, are subject to license restrictions and are not shipped by default for all platforms (http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/soundbanks.html) and requires separate download and a multi-step setup to work.

**The Answer**: Gervill

http://java.net/projects/gervill/pages/Home

> Gervill was designed to be generic
>   synthesizer for Java. By adding
>   gervill.jar to your classpath you
>   should be able to load SoundFonts/DLS
>   files using MidiSystem.getSoundBank().
>   And MidiSystem.getSynthesizer() should
>   return instance of Gervill
>   Synthesizer.

It's an open source 100% pure java implementation of the general MIDI sounds banks.  You simply drop gervill.jar in the classpath and that's it.  Your gm sound banks will be made available to your app.

Comment: I am not really sure that that is the issue. I am reading the midi soundbank as a resource from the jar. I am not loading the default systems soundbank. The issue seems to be more of a classloader problem, on some OS's. When I try to call the getInstrumentName which only occurs after the the class has been instantiated (the array should be populated within the constructor). This has been tested on different machines running the same version of java